# Unity Input Manager Swipe Controls Not Registering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access my horizontal input from my CrossPlatformInputManager, this works fine when using my mouse.

```
CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis(_verticalAxisName);
```

However when I'm using my touch screen this doesn't work.

My Mouse can only control the swipe pad with the right click instead of the left.  I also have a mobile joystick on the page, in the center which works fine with left click.  I have a feeling that if can get the crossplatform manager to register with the left click then the touch screen will work.

How can I get the CrossPlatformManager to work with left click?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. You want to detect a drag on an object?

Comment: I'm using the standard swipe script from the cross platform input manager however it's not detecting swipes

Comment: Ok. Is the swipe on a Sprite/Sprite renderer or 3D mesh? It looks like there is a better way to do this but I need to know what you mean by swipe. Move the mouse over across the object? Also, are you going to be doing anything during the swipe or after the swipe ends? I just need to know what you are doing in order to provide better answer.

Comment: I'm using unity 5's new swipe pad control, which is an import package under asset, import package cross platform input.  Which basically creates a touch image with a touch pad script provided by the new unity 5

Comment: I figured out what was going on the input but it's very wierd the input on a touch screen won't register until after a long press

Comment: I'm going to close this and create a new question thank you for the help so far programmer

Comment: No problem. Make sure to explain what you are trying to do in the next question.